# Why do we need to activate/deactivate the feature in case of module project when deploying file?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page

What is the pupose of the feature when deploying masterpage via VS 2012 module project?

I tested and noticed that deactivating this feature does not remove the masterpage from the _catalogs/masterpage directory. Then, why do we use feature for deploying masterpage via VS modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The master page won't be removed automatically. You will need to write the code in the feature deactivated event to delete the mater page from the _catalogs library.

Comment: I think the purpose of using feature event receiver is to only set/revert the master page.. Then, why at all create a feature? I am getting confused. Please help me

Comment: If you don't create a feature for setting/reverting the master page, then you will need to apply the master page manually or delete it when you no longer need it. However, feature will help in automation.

Comment: OK, so if I do not want to use automatic file deletion and I do not want to deactivate the master page automatically, then can I delete the feature and deploy the solution via VS?

Comment: Yes, in that case the module is enough to place the master page in the _catalogs library. There on wards you can set it manually.

Comment: Nadeem can you give me code to delete the masterpage file on feature deactivation or uninstall ?

Comment: See these for reference:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/49ee8a71-e18a-4a4e-90c6-a5c9547138f3/how-to-programmatically-remove-master-pages-and-page-layouts-?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560940/delete-custom-master-page-error-on-feature-deactivation

Comment: HI Nadeem, I notice that the files from the mapped layout folder (TEMPLATE/GLOBAL) gets deleted once we retract a solution. However, files deployed to the '_catalogs/masterpage' do not get deleted. Is this correct behaviour?

Comment: Yes that is expected behavior.

Comment: Ok, so all layout files will be deleted on feature deactivation automatically. But, all the SP files (catalog folder) will have to be explicitly coded for deletion in feature deactivation part